# C# this.Invalidate() is blocking parent form to access

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, invalidation

I have a VS2010 solution (tried mimicking my main issue) which has 2 project and each project has one windows form each. **Mainform** is in project_1 which has reference to project 2 where **ChildForm** is defined.

I have a button on MainForm whose button click event creates a **ChildForm** and shows. While ChildForm is shown, i can invoke any menu commands (each menu command is implemented to show a message box) which are defined on **MainForm** without any issues.

BUT, on other hand, I kept all the code as is and override OnPaint method of ChildForm with this.Invalidate() as shown below

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

I ran executable and it opened up my MainForm and clicked on button to open up my ChildForm, then clicked on one of the Menu command to raise a message box, then I found that both MainForm and ChildForms are frozen and are hanged without any response.

Can anyone put some light on what went wrong with overriding OnPaint method which executes this.Invalidate() line everytime and suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 1):

You called `Invalidate()` which will fire `OnPaint`, `OnPaint` calls `Invalidate()` and again ... that's a loop of calling `Invalidate()` and `OnPaint`  -> Your UI is frozen.

The solution is you have to make it more clear on what you want and your purpose of overriding `OnPaint` here.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply. Basically, my intention is to rotate/spin a DirectX 3D model on a WinForm's panel continuously. So, to achieve that, I had to override OnPaint method where I will be changing the directX 3D parameters and redrawing the graphics object by forcing this.validate();

It work fine if my ChildForm, where I am rotating 3D model, is the my MainForm. I would not invoke any functionality of my MainForm by rotating 3D model on ChildForm continuously. 

Please let me know if further information is needed.

Regards,

Comment: @Kumar it's still not clear to me. You can call `Invalidate()` in the `OnPaint` of another object and vice-versa but you can't call `Invalidate()` in the `OnPaint` of the same object. BTW, drawing a 3D model should be done by some `DirectX` lib using some special control (not `Form`), or by using `WPF`.

Comment: That's a great information and thanks for that. Could you please let me know what kind of special controls can be used to display 3D models using DirectX lib? Please put some light on it so that I will explore further.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: @Kumar it's a pity that I don't know it well, you should search for it.